# Ruby - how to enforce sequential execution

Tags: ruby, class, refactoring

I have a number of tasks that must be completed in sequence. After refactoring the task logic from methods into separate classes, I'm seeing their performance is no longer guaranteed to be sequential (i.e. the second and third task start before the first is complete). What's going on here and how should I go about ensuring sequential performance?

The original code looked like:

```
class MyClass
  def do_stuff
    do_first_thing
    do_second_thing
    do_third_thing
  end # each waits for its predecessor to finish before starting

  def do_first_thing
    # takes a minute to complete
  end

  def do_second_thing
    # takes a minute to complete
  end

  def do_third_thing
    # takes a minute to complete
  end
end
```

The refactored code looks like:

```
class MyClass
  def do_stuff
    FirstThing.new.do_it
    SecondThing.new.do_it
    ThirdThing.new.do_it
  end # for some reason, each doesn't wait for its predecessor to finish before starting
end

class FirstThing
  def do_it
    # takes a minute to complete
  end
end

class SecondThing
  def do_it
    # takes a minute to complete
  end
end

class ThirdThing
  def do_it
    # takes a minute to complete
  end
end
```

EDIT: no threading or parallel processing is going on or desired.

EDIT: I used the following code to try to replicate my problem and it seems to be working, so maybe the problem lies somewhere else. I will post progress and results here.

```
#
# OLD VERSION
#

class OldJob
  def work_it
    move_it
    shake_it
    bake_it
  end

  def move_it
    puts "MOVING IT..."
    sleep 5
  end

  def shake_it
    puts "SHAKING IT..."
    sleep 5
  end

  def bake_it
    puts "BAKING IT..."
    sleep 5
  end
end

OldJob.new.work_it

puts "-----------"

#
# NEW VERSION
#

class MoveJob
  def do_it
    puts "MOVING IT..."
    sleep 5
  end
end

class ShakeJob
  def do_it
    puts "SHAKING IT..."
    sleep 5
  end
end

class BakeJob
  def do_it
    puts "BAKING IT..."
    sleep 5
  end
end

class NewJob
  def work_it
    MoveJob.new.do_it
    ShakeJob.new.do_it
    BakeJob.new.do_it
  end
end

NewJob.new.work_it
```

results as expected in:

```
ruby  --->> ruby ~/Desktop/my_job.rb 
MOVING IT...
SHAKING IT...
BAKING IT...
-----------
MOVING IT...
SHAKING IT...
BAKING IT...
```

FINAL EDIT:

So it turns out in my haste to refactor into multiple similar classes, I had misnamed some of the class names, which caused their execution to not happen. Dependent classes therefore did not have access to the results of the previous process because it had not taken place. Its interesting to note I did not see any errors pertaining to class name ambiguity, which was the root cause.

My issue is resolved. Please feel free to delete?/close this question.

Comment: You might want to provide more info about what exactly is going on in your methods, b/c it sounds like you're doing some asynchronous processing in your methods, which means you'll have to rework some stuff to get them evaluating in order.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: I would agree with @GPD2 here. The code you post will work sequentially.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code in the question cannot by itself cause the symptoms that are described.

Comment: With more detail, this could be an interesting question.  If you figure out what is needed to cause the non-deterministic order, will you please edit the question to show it?

Comment: You can delete your own post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm figuring your tasks are running in separate threads because otherwise they would be sequential.

Assuming they are running in separate threads, you can make it sequential using callbacks. These are more common in Javascript, but certainly doable in Ruby as well.

Example of defining the tasks to accept callbacks

```
class FirstThing
  def do_it(&callback)
    Thread.new do
      # do stuff
      callback.call
    end
  end
end
```

Then run the first task, invoking the second task in the callback:

```
FirstThing.new.run do
  SecondThing.new.run
end
```

Note that your `MyClass#do_stuff` method will return immediately, not wait for the callbacks to finish. Without some kind of blocking loop, it's impossible to make asynchronous code synchronous.

Comment: Is it `do_it`, `run` or `do_stuff`? :)